# How to show null value in html table?

Tags: html, unix

I have input data in a file like this.

```
A,B,C
,D,E
F,,G
```

I want to show output like this.

```
Column1 Column2 Column3
A       B       C
        D       E
F               G
```

But, I am getting output like this.

```
Column1 Column2 Column3
A       B       C
D       E
F       G
```

From above input data, I am reading each line in while loop Unix. I am substistuting , by new line. I am getting each and every value correctly. But, I am not able to show in proper format as required in html. 
Could you please help for formatting?

Comment: What language are you looping in? Can you show us your code?

Comment: What you want to output and the output you get is the same? That oftenly indicates you already reached your goal and just run out of cofee

Comment: @RupertMadden-Abbott- I am looping in UNIX.

Comment: @user1902288- I am getting output. I am not getting it in proper format. Please observe above sample example.

Comment: You haven’t shown any HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

Spacings are trimmed in HTML, use `&nbsp;` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>A</td>
         <td>B</td>
         <td>C</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
         <td>D</td>
         <td>E</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>F</td>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
         <td>G</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and Style is below

```
table tr td{padding:10px;}
```

Now you got the expected output

Answer (score 0):

If you are reading a file with blank spaces you can use \r\n . \r is the end of line for Windows systems and the \n is the end of line for unix systems. \t is the representation for a tab. I wish I knew what language you were parsing this in to be of more help.